# Edit a gist using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, github, gist

How do I update a gist using ajax? I tried this:

```
$.support.cors = true;
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    //method: 'PATCH',
    //method: 'POST',
    //type: 'PATCH',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/<GIST_ID>',
    data: '{"description" : "some description text","public" : true, "files" : { "myfile.txt" : { "content" : "file edited via ajax", "filename" : "myfile.txt" } }}',
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization","Basic <USER>:<PASS>");
    }
}).done(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

The [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/#edit-a-gist) does not provide a clear example.

It returns a JSON and status OK 200 but the gist is not updated.

If I use method to `POST` it will give status 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote this javascript object that handles it all:

```
/**
* Credit: http://techslides.com/github-gist-api-with-curl-and-ajax
* https://developer.github.com/v3/gists/

* @example
* var g = new Gist();
* g.gistID = 'ae7f4db52bbf76051e25e26fb05712c0';
* g.token = '2590a460f653d23c4f61c6774b7a41296aea9028';
*
* g.create({
*    description: 'new gist',
*    public: true,
*    files: {
*        'file1.txt': {
*            'content': 'file contents'
*       }
*     }
* }, function(data) {
*        // callback
* });
*/

var Gist = function() {

    $.support.cors = true; // Whithout this ajax will not work in IE 9.
    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); // Disable ajax cache globally.

    this.gistID = '';
    this.token = '';

    var self = this;

    this.newToken = function(user, pass, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/authorizations',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(user + ':' + pass));
            },
            data: JSON.stringify({
                scopes: ['gist'],
                note: 'new token request from ajax ' + new Date()
            })
        }).always(function(data, txtStatus, err) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(data);
        });
    }

    this.create = function(data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/gists',
            type: 'POST',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'token ' + self.token);
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).always(function(data, txtStatus, err) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(data);
        });
    }

    this.edit = function(data, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://api.github.com/gists/' + self.gistID,
            type: 'PATCH',
            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'token ' + self.token);
            },
            data: JSON.stringify(data)
        }).always(function(data, txtStatus, err) {
            if (typeof callback === 'function') callback(data);
        });
    }
}
```

*Credit: http://techslides.com/github-gist-api-with-curl-and-ajax*